# What is a namespace in java security model

Tags: java, classloader, java-security

In java security model, the class loader subsystem often uses the notation of namespaces to load classes. I'd like to ask what actually is a namespace,how it it used in class loading by class loaders in jvm and how does it fit into the java security model. Is it related to package name somehow ? Please explain.

Comment: What Java document used the term "namespace" in the context of Java Security?

Comment: https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/securityP.html This document seems quite relevant.

Comment: That is not a Java document, but someone else writing about it and using that term. It refers to chapter 8. Did you find/read *their* definition of the term?

Comment: Yes I did read it but couldn't really grasp its meaning.

Comment: From chapter 8: *"the separate namespaces awarded to each class loader"*. This means that each classloader defines a separate namespace, i.e. two independent classloaders can have different classes with the exact same fully qualified name.

Comment: Alright then, from my understanding all a namespace is, a collection of UNIQUE class names and this collection is maintained for each classloader. Is this correct ? Then can a classloader have only one namespace or it can have multiple.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot .